# Keeping track of the path of binary tree

Tags: c++, tree

I'm working on an exercise that represents a certain binary tree with LEDs. I already have the binary tree, I think:

```
NodeB::NodeB(int data)
{
  _left = NULL;
  _right = NULL;

  _data = data;
}

int NodeB::getdata(){
    return _data;
}

int NodeB::adddata(int data){
    int toReturn;

    if(data >= _data){
        if(_right == NULL){
            NodeB* n = new NodeB(data);
            _right = n;
            toReturn = 1;
        }

        else{
            toReturn = _right->adddata(data);
        }
    }

    else{
        if(_left == NULL){
            NodeB* n = new NodeB(data);
            _left = n;
            toReturn = -1;
        }

        else{
            toReturn = _left->adddata(data);
        }
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

---

I also have a matrix:

```
int matrix[3][2][4] = { { {line1, controlr, controlg, line2}, {controlr, line1, controlg, line2} },
                    { {line1, controlg, controlr, line2}, {controlg, line1, controlr, line2} },
                    { {line2, controlg, controlr, line1}, {controlg, line2, controlr, line1} } };
```

with the data that turn on each LED. Each LED represents a node.

---

In order to be able to turn on the correct LEDs, I need to know how the tree is looking. For example, root, its left node, and a child of the left node.

I think that this may be accomplished by using a 3x2 `bool` array, which knows which LEDs should be turned on.

The question finally is, how can I get to know which index of the 3x2 `bool` array to mark `true`? Since `add data(int data)` uses recursion, perhaps using an array containing "lefts and rights" might not be the best option (aside for my ineptitude to make that possibility work…).

What should I do here?

Comment: This seems pretty cool, but I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking here. Can you clarify a bit about what you want to do with the LEDs and what structural information you need access to?

Comment: @templatetypedef I am trying to represent the binary tree real-time with LEDs. The problem with having LEDs is that in order to turn on more than one at a time, you need to "quickly turn on and off" all the LEDs you need to use. For that reason, I need to keep track of the nodes that I've added to the tree. Is it a bit clearer?